# Get clickable anchor from database inside div

Tags: php, html

I have text field in database stored like that :

```html
I like my <a href='www.website.com'>Website</a>
```

So my variable is:

```
$text = "I like my <a href='www.website.com'>Website</a> ";
```

and when i fetch it i get it like that

```html
I like my <a href='www.website.com'>Website</a>
```

How can i get it clickable like that ? thanks

> I like my [Website](http://www.website.com)

Comment: I can't see where is the problem. Both of the `html`s looks the same.. (`I like my <a href='www.website.com'>Website</a>`). Maybe you mean `I like my &lt;a href=&#39;www.website.com&#39;&gt;Website&lt;/a&gt;` is the server response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to echo your text

```
echo $text;
```

If you receive encoded text, than use some decoding:

```
echo html_entity_decode($text);
```

Comment: @MoshFeu Sorry, hit submit too soon :D

Comment: @ScooterDaraf Because `htmlentities` will encode HTML, removing actual link